# Using object slicing for effective assignment

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, object-slicing

Let's say I have the definitions

```
struct A{
    int a1 = 0;
    int a2 = 1;
};

struct B: public A{
    int b1 = 2;
    int b2 = 3;
};
```

And I have a B object that I'm going to call `foo`, and I want to update its fields inherited from A to the values in another A object that I call `bar`. Obviously I could just do this by assigning each field, but could object slicing be used here instead?

I tried using this code

```
(A) foo = bar;
```

but it doesn't modify the fields, which I'm guessing is because I'm somehow making a copy. So can I use object slicing to do this, and if so is it 1.) not UB and 2.) reasonable?

Comment: Do the most descriptive, easy-to-understand thing until forced to do something less descriptive. Even if it worked, what you're trying to do will have a lot of programmers looking at the code and wondering what you really mean to do.

Comment: `(A) foo` creates a temporary `A` object, it doesn't allows to modify `foo` as if it was an `A`.  Why not just give `B` an `operator =(const A&)` function?

Comment: Fwiw, `(A&) foo = bar;` will probably do what you very-strangely seem to want. I concur with @NathanOliver, however. Just make a proper operator in the first place.

Comment: `static_cast<A&>(b_obj) = a_obj;` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/d3eGeb8WM

Comment: Please provide [mcve] in form of code! start with: https://godbolt.org/z/qhW5v5fda

Comment: @OP Maybe you didn't think this thing all the way through.  If a client was able to do `(A) foo = bar;`, then the client would also expect to construct a `B` object from an `A` object.  You only focused on assignment, but not construction.